# WPF View Model update but View not update

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I use MVVM when I update view model programmatically view does not update.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

my model :

```
public class Payment:ViewModelBase
{
    private long _paymentId;
    private decimal _price;

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long PaymentId {
        get { return _paymentId; }
        set
        {
            _paymentId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PaymentId));
        }
    }

    public decimal Price {
        get { return _price; }
        set
        {
            _price = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Price));
        }
    }
}
```

my view model :

```
class PaymentFactorViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public PaymentFactorViewModel()
    {
        PaymentFactor = new PaymentFactor();
        PaymentFactor.Price=350,000;
    }

    private Payment _paymentFactor;
    public Payment PaymentFactor
    {
        get { return _paymentFactor; }
        set
        {
            _paymentFactor = value;
            
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PaymentFactor));
        }
    }
}
```

my view :

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtPrice" Text="{Binding PaymentFactor.Price,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged"/>
```

when I change TextBox.Text ViewModel will update, but when I change ViewModel programmatically View does not update.

For example I set PaymentFactor.Price=350,000 in ViewModel constructor but TextBox.Text is 0.

Comment: What is `PaymentFactor`? You have posted only `Payment`.

Comment: It's a model of Payment in my view model.

Comment: You didn't specify datacontext, forexample elementname

Comment: Besides, please show the full xaml code

Comment: I define DataContext in Xaml : **<Window.DataContext><viewModel:PaymentFactorViewModel/></Window.DataContext>**

Comment: Where and how do you set the view model property?

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in the code you posted.

PaymentFactorViewmodel should be public

Lose the , in 350000

You don't have a PaymentFactor class, you have Payment. I don't see how that piece of code can even compile.

The below works ok for me. Or at least it shows 350000 as I'd expect.

I put everything in the one namespace.

```
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1200">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:PaymentFactorViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtPrice" Text="{Binding PaymentFactor.Price,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>


public class PaymentFactorViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public PaymentFactorViewModel()
    {
        PaymentFactor = new Payment();
        PaymentFactor.Price=350000;
    }

    private Payment _paymentFactor;
    public Payment PaymentFactor
    {
        get { return _paymentFactor; }
        set
        {
            _paymentFactor = value;
       
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PaymentFactor));
        }
    }
}

public class Payment:ViewModelBase
{
    private long _paymentId;
    private decimal _price;
    public long PaymentId {
        get { return _paymentId; }
        set
        {
            _paymentId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PaymentId));
        }
    }

    public decimal Price {
        get { return _price; }
        set
        {
            _price = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Price));
        }
    }
}
```